# How to sample a column based on frequency in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Currently have following datatable

[image]

As you can see the probability of 1 occurring is 30%, 2 is 50% and 3 is 20%

I want to sample the values in this column based on that probability

so i would want something like this

[image]

As you can see - the first two columns are unaffected

any ideas on how to do this - i think the sample function would help but not sure how to get it working

Comment: Can you explain the logic of `col3` in details?

Comment: I just created i as an example. it only contains those 3 values and the porbabilities are what i have created

Comment: There are no further rows - how can i re arrange the values in that column based on the probabilities of the values occuring - so i would want  2 to appear 50% of the time - here in example is 5 times to make it easy to understand!

Comment: `df$col3 <- sample(df$col3)` ?

Comment: ?^ given below as answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would just be to shuffle the column...

```
df$col3 <- sample(df$col3)
```

Comment: i need the probabilities to occur as often as they do? will this work for example 1 has to be appearing only 30% of the time?

Comment: Yes, `col3` will contain exactly the same numbers, just in a different order, so the frequencies must be the same.

Comment: will this work if i have the same values in col3, with the same probabilities but have like 100 rows? all i want is the probabilities to be the same as the rows increase - so if 100 rows then 2 should appear  50% of the time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-create the column with the desired probabilities instead of just shuffling its current values:

```
df$col3sample <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) sample(3, size=1, prob=c(0.3, 0.5, 0.2), replace=TRUE))
```

This will create a new column in `df` with a 1, 2, or 3 assigned to each row drawn with probability 0.3/0.5/0.2.

```
   col1   col2 col3 col3sample
1    ab    red    2          3
2    as   blue    1          1
3    ad  green    2          2
4    af orange    1          2
5    ag  black    2          2
6    ah    red    1          1
7    aw  green    2          2
8    we orange    3          3
9    wr  black    2          1
10   et  white    3          2
```

This does allow for some random variation in the probability distribution, however, so you may have to take a few samples to get it to be exactly 30% 1s, 50% 2s, and 20% 3s.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could elaborate a bit on the solution.
This may work as a one-liner but can be harder to wrap your head around.

Comment: I added some additional explanation and output.